# What is the difference between dplyr::matches and stringr::str_view?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I'm trying to extract all columns from a data.frame that are named with 4 uppercase letters.

I can find the columns alright when I name the letters specifically, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(
  abc = NA,
  abcd = NA,
  ABCD = NA,
  ABCDEF = NA,
  abcdefg = NA
)

str_view(names(df),"^[ABCDEFG]{4}$")
select(df,matches("^[ABCDEFG]{4}$", ignore.case = FALSE))
```

which both return only the ABCD column.

But when I try to use the special `[:upper:]` class, it works in `str_view` but not with matches...

```
str_view(names(df),"^[:upper:]{4}$")
select(df,matches("^[:upper:]{4}$"))
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something here?

Comment: You should be using `select(df,matches("^[[:upper:]]{4}$", ignore.case=FALSE))` for the character class with dplyr. This is consistent with the base `grep()` function

Comment: Ok thanks @MrFlick, works perfectly. 

Does this mean that the underlying regex parser is different between the two functions? I naively thought `str_view` was meant to test regexes before inputting them elsewhere

Comment: Must be. By most definitions the one what works with str_view should be invalid.